# How to combine 2 different arraylist from 2 different classes into a new arraylist in a different class?

Tags: java, collections

I have 3 class: person, teacher and student. Student and teacher have respective arraylists storing the records of student & teacher respectively.

```
public class StudentTable {
static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>(); //code to add students
```

Teacher class:

```
public class TeacherTable {
static List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>(); //code to add teachers
```

I have created a new list List persons in PersonTable class, want to merge the above 2 lists in the same. I unable to understand how to use merge these in a different class. Please help.

Comment: I would re-structure the entire thing -- get those static fields out of their respective classes, make them instance (non-static) and put them in the class that actually uses them.

Comment: You shouldn’t use `static` variables, but anyway, `List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(); persons.addAll(StudentTable.students);  persons.addAll(TeacherTable.teachers);`, whats your question? What do you mean with “how to use merge”?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would start but removing the `static` keyword for your `List`'s.

Then I would create a class called `Person` that has Attributes and Behaviors of a person. Keep your `StudentTable` and `TeacherTable` but remove/add attributes and behaviors that describe only a `StudentTable` OR `TeacherTable` respectively.

Make your `Student` and `Teacher` classes also by initializing a student or teacher of type `Person`. Then initialize each `StudentTable` and `TeacherTable` with lists of type `Person` containing those `Teacher` and `Student`.

Lastly, add your `StudentTable` and `TeacherTable` into an `List` of type `Person` like so `List<Person>`.

Something like this

```
class Person
{
   //Attributes of a person

   public Person() //Parameters to initialize a Person
   {
      // Initialize Person object
   }
   //Behaviors of a person
}

public class StudentTable 
{
   List<Person> students = new ArrayList<>(); //code to add students
}

public class TeacherTable 
{
   List<Person> teachers = new ArrayList<>(); //code to add teachers
}

public class PersonTable
{
   List<Person> list;
   // other instance variables
   public StudentTable(List<Person> teachers, List<Person> students)
   {
      //initialize PersonTable
   }
}
```

Let me know if you are confused by any of this and I will try to help or if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that a Student and Teacher must inherit something similar in order to be grouped together. For example.

```java
interface Person {

}

class Student implements Person {

}

class Teacher implements Person {

}
```

Now we can group these objects as Person objects, using Java 8's stream for example.

```java
List<Student> students = ...; // all students

List<Teacher> teachers = ...; // all teachers

List<Person> persons = Stream.concat(students.stream(), teachers.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Feel free to comment if you're going to downvote. Maybe I read the question wrong :/

Comment: My guess is because you didn't read it carefully. The OP has a person class not a person interface.